# How do I compare values of an Object with the StreamAPI and Lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I got a problem with streams.
I'm trying to compare everything in my LinkedList to get the latest Medium with the StreamAPI.
The problem I run into is that my methode **sucheNeuesMedium()** throws **NoSuchElementExeption**, because **get()** finds no value. The stream is filled with elements *(befor anyone says "be sure that you got objects in your list")*.
I want to compare them by the value of "Jahr" *(it has to be with the StreamAPI and Lambda expressions)*.
Any ideas how I can make this run? If you need further information I will supply you.

```
    //In class Medienverwaltung
    LinkedList<Medium> liste = new LinkedList<Medium>();
    Iterator<Medium> it = liste.iterator(); //irrelevant for this task
    Stream<Medium> stream = liste.stream();

    public Medium sucheNeuesMedium() {
        return stream.max(Comparator.comparing(Medium::getJahr)).get();
    }

    //In abstract class Medium
    public int getJahr() {
        return jahr;
    }
```

Comment: Where in that code are you adding anything to `liste`? The Optional returned by `Stream.max` will only be empty if the stream is empty - which it is in the code you have shown us. Show us an actual [mre]

Comment: You initialize `liste` with an empty list. Hence, `it` will be initialized to a stream of an empty list (i.e. an empty stream). No data in stream -> no elements -> no max element -> empty `Optional` -> `NoSuchElementException` on `get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error: I have to operate with `liste.stream()` and then my comparison.
I always tried it on Imported objects (serialized), meaning the stream stayed empty (the stream got initialized with the empty list).
But if I use `liste.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Medium::getJahr)).get();`
it works flawless and multiple times not once. I didn't think about the stream being used aswell. It works, but still thanks for the fast answers.